# Two images captured by camera and not able to delete one from DCIM/Camera folder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-7.1-nougat

I'm capturing image from my Nougat device, and I'm storing image in ABC folder, works fine. After capturing image I'm sending them to server and once it get uploaded I'm deleting images from ABC folder till here it works fine, But I have noticed camera is creating two images one stored in ABC folder and another one in DCIM/Camera folder. Also I'm specifying the name of captured image while saving, but one in DCIM/Camera has system generated name, Please guide how to delete that image from DCIM/Camera folder Here is my code

Open camera

```
 private void openCamera() {
    destination = null;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        try {
            String originalfileName = getFilenameOrgImage();
            File root = new File(ConstantData.IMAGE_STORAGE_LOCAL_PATH + File.separator);
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            destination = new File(originalfileName);
            Log.d("destination",destination.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.
                        getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", destination);
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CommonMethods.showToast(this, getResources().getString(R.string.please_try_again));
        }
    } else {
        CommonMethods.showToast(this, getResources().getString(R.string.camera_doesnt_support));
    }
}
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 10;
                    Log.d("IMAGE",destination.getAbsolutePath());
                    treeDetailsModels.get(imgClickPos).setName(imagename);
                    treeDetailsModels.get(imgClickPos).setImgDestinationPath(destination);

                    View v = viewPager.findViewWithTag("pos" + imgClickPos);
                    ImageView ivBackground = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
                    ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Custom location

```
public static final String IMAGE_STORAGE_LOCAL_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString() + "/ABC";
```

Added this provide to manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Path

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="ABC/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Your post and your code is a mesh. You talk about ABC folder but ABC is nowhere in your code. Instead you use ConstantData.IMAGE_STORAGE_LOCAL_PATH. Then in onActivityResult you mess around with a bitmap. Why? Is it relevant for the problem? And you have a compressImage(destination.getAbsolutePath()); statement which you did not tell. And nobody knows what it does. Moreover you did not mention your file provider. Remove all code from onActivityResult and inspect if you still get two files.

Answer (score 2):

> But I have noticed camera is creating two images one stored in ABC folder and another one in DCIM/Camera folder

Your code is starting a third-party camera app. That app was written by other programmers, and those programmers can do whatever they want. They *should not* be saving the image twice, but they are welcome to do so.

> Please guide how to delete that image from DCIM/Camera folder

There are ~2 billion Android devices, with hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps and hundreds more camera apps available from the Play Store and elsewhere. Any of those hundreds of camera apps could be launched by your code. Any of those camera apps can do whatever they want. Some may create extra copies of the photo. Some may upload the photo to their servers. Some may modify the photo. Most, hopefully, will do none of these things... but you do not get a vote.

So, your choices are:

1. Live with the side effects of some camera apps, such as extra copies of the image, or
2. Stop taking photos using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (either take the photos yourself using the camera hardware, or just stop taking photos entirely)